# If I "will" need the service you provide, will/do/should I call you or message you? - is the "will" needed?

Tags: future-constructions

**Example 1**

> If they **will** let me go to the university, will/do/should I call you or message you?

**Example 2**

> If I **will** need the service you provide, will/do/should I call you or message you?

Which one is acceptable?

The if-clause is in a future sense. But is the "will" needed?

In the main clause, which one do I use? Will or Do or Should?

Comment: There is no "will" in an "if" clause. "If" + simple present creates the future meaning on its own

Answer (score 0):

**Will** is not needed.

> If I need the service you provide (*at some time in the future* is implied), should I call you?

**Do** could be used instead (in the sense *is it the proper thing to do?*)